# Ubuntu 12.04 ROS Fuerte Gazebo install Problem

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu-precise, ros-fuerte, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been trying to install ROS on several different computers now.  I have also tried installing on multiple different Ubuntu systems, each time I get the following error when I try and start Gazebo using, **roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch**.

> process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [16887]

> /home/ncroscup/ros/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2: /home/ncroscup /ros/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzclient: No such file or directory

> [empty_world_server-2] process has died [pid 16879, exit code 127, cmd /home/ncroscup/ros/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /home/ncroscup/ros/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=empty_world_server __log:=/home/ncroscup/.ros/log/716587de-ca01-11e1-8ac1-90f652b11550/empty_world_server-2.log].

> log file: /home/ncroscup/.ros/log/716587de-ca01-11e1-8ac1-90f652b11550/empty_world_server-2*.log

> [gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 16887, exit code 127, cmd /home/ncroscup/ros/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/ncroscup/.ros/log/716587de-ca01-11e1-8ac1-90f652b11550/gazebo_gui-3.log].

> log file: /home/ncroscup/.ros/log/716587de-ca01-11e1-8ac1-90f652b11550/gazebo_gui-3*.log

I followed instruction from the Ubuntu home site,
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

along with startup instructions of Gazebo from,
http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo

I've looked for the errors and have come to the conclusion that it may be a driver issue, but I have tried several different video cards.  Currently using Gefore 8600 GT, which is said to be compatible.

I'm starting to wonder if this actually works... should I downgrade to ros electric?

Very frustrated I've had to put so much time into this and still have no idea what to try next.  It's been over a week of reinstalling on 3 different machines, and 5 different partitions... trying all possible issues I could think of... any suggestions? really would like to get this working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38308/ubuntu-12.04-ros-fuerte-gazebo-install-problem/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-09**:
I doubt anyone will be able to help unless you post relevant parts of the error log. (Please format them with four leading spaces on each line.)

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-07-09**:
Im not really familiar with Gazebo or any of the issue you are having, so this may be a stupid comment.  The line that says "....gazebo/bin/gzclient: No such file or directory" really stands out though.  This looks like an executable.  Is it there?  Did Gazebo install correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I think you did not install gazebo properly. Maybe you can go to Synaptic Package Manager to check if you have all of the gazebo related packages installed.

---

Originally posted by [shuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2772/shuo/) with karma: 28 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1